# only go to next iteration when something is clicked

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Okay so I'm asking questions in a pop quiz on my web page.
The questions are randomly generated in a loop that kind of looks like this:

```
for(var ii=1;ii<=numQuestions;ii++){        
    var tempScore = askQuestion(difficulty)
}
```

askQuestion() basically creates a question and 4 possible answers (1 is correct) and puts it on the web page. The only thing is, it does all the iterations before I can even answer one. Is there some way I can wait until some class is clicked on before going to the next iteration?

EDIT: I guess a better way to state this question is, how can I make the function askQuestion() only finish and return when a button is clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var numQuestions = 10;

askQuestion(difficulty);

$('button').click(function() {

    numQuestions--;

    if (numQuestions > 0) {

        askQuestion(difficulty);

    } else {
        //all questions have been answered

    }
});
```

Comment: ou I like this, no for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple recursive approach

```
function nextQuestion(i) {
    var tempScore = askQuestion(difficulty);
    if(i < numQuestions) {//do processing/wait for event
        document.querySelector(".xxx").addEventListener("click", function() {
            nextQuestion(i+1);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There's problem here, addEventListener will be called mutiple times if the button is not re-created with "askQuestion"